# Count average age from database, merge 2 queries

Tags: php, mysql

Ok so I don't think the question is as simple as the title suggests but here goes ...
I have this query:

```
SELECT age.*, job.id FROM age, job WHERE ((age.aid = job.id) AND (age.aid='$id'))
```

this basically joins the two tables age and job and gets matching rows

but now I need to find the most common age stored in row guess under the table age

**DB layout**

Table: *age*

rows: *aid - guess*

Table: *job*

Rows: *id*

From what I have found searching I need to use count()

eg:

```
SELECT guess, COUNT(guess) AS countguess FROM age GROUP BY guess ORDER BY countguess DESC LIMIT 1
```

but how can I merge the 2 queries together?

Comment: What do you mean by guess?  Guess is a very vague term, and computers are incapable of making guesses anyway.

Comment: "guess" is a row name within the age table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
SELECT age.aid, job.id, age.guess, COUNT(age.guess) AS countguess 
FROM age, job 
WHERE ((age.aid = job.id) AND (age.aid='$id')) 
GROUP BY guess 
ORDER BY countguess DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say merge, i think you mean joining them. You can join when there is a relationship between the 2 tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION ALL` to accomplish this

```
SELECT aid, id, guess, SUM(countguess ) AS countguess
FROM
(
 SELECT age.aid, job.id, guess, 0 AS countguess  
 FROM age
      INNER JOIN job
          ON age.aid = job.id AND 
             age.aid='$id'

 UNION ALL

 SELECT age.aid, 0 AS job.id, guess, COUNT(guess) AS countguess 
 FROM age 
 GROUP BY guess 
 ORDER BY countguess DESC 
 LIMIT 1
) a
GROUP BY aid
```

*Note: `UNION ALL` requires same number of columns in both queries

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT age.*, job.id FROM age, job,
    (SELECT AVG(guess) AS countguess FROM age GROUP BY guess ORDER BY countguess DESC LIMIT 1) AS countguess
FROM job AS j
INNER JOIN age AS a
ON j.id = a.aid
WHERE a.aid = '{$id}'
```

I'm not sure if this is what you want? Maybe

```
SELECT age.*, job.id FROM age, job,
    (SELECT AVG(guess) AS countguess FROM age WHERE guess = a.guess GROUP BY '1') AS countguess
FROM job AS j
INNER JOIN age AS a
ON j.id = a.aid
WHERE a.aid = '{$id}'
```